# P5.js and nested loops

Tags: javascript, processing, nested-loops, p5.js

I'm very new to JavaScript and the P5.js library and I'm currently attempting to get my head around nested loops. I'm attempting to iterate both x position and fill transparency and I've got it working using a *while* loop, however when I attempt to create a nested *for* loop, I come undone.

Here is the *while* loop:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 200);
}

function draw() {
  //background colour
  background(0,0,0);
  
  let x = 20;
  let alpha = 50;
  
  while (x <= width){
    fill(255,255,255,alpha);
    rect(x,70,60,60);
    alpha = alpha + 50;
    x = x + 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

And here is my attempt at a *for* nested loop:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 200);
}

function draw() {
  //background colour
  background(0,0,0);  
   
  for (x = 20; x <= width; x = x + 100){
    for (alpha = 50; alpha < 255; alpha = alpha + 50){
      fill(255,255,255,alpha);
      rect(x,70,60,60);
    }  
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I've spent 2 hours attempting everything that I can think of to get it working, it's time to get some help.

Would I be correct in assuming that I'm going about this the wrong way, *alpha* is a P5 function and is obviously causing the console output above? The while loop works, but I am very much attempting to understand how loops work and this will help me a great deal. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested loop is the wrong approach for this task. You have to use a nested loop when you want to iterate through an 2 dimensional array (for instance a grid), but it is completely useless and superfluous for a 1 dimensional case (like a line or row). In this case you can iterate the control variables in one loop:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 200);
}

function draw() {
    //background colour
    background(0,0,0);  
   
    for (let x = 20, alpha = 50; x <= width; x += 100, alpha += 50){
        fill(255, 255, 255, alpha);
        rect(x, 70, 60, 60);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

You can use a nested loop to iterates the x and the the y coordinates of rectangles arranged to a grid:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 200);
}

function draw() {
    //background colour
    background(0,0,0);  
   
    let alpha = 50;
    for (let y = 20; y <= height; y += 100) {
        for (let x = 20; x <= width; x += 100) {
            fill(255, 255, 255, alpha);
            rect(x, y, 60, 60);
            alpha += 10;
        }  
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that! 

I was watching a Coding Train video with Dan Schiffman on two dimensional arrays and got ahead of myself! I was over complicating things for myself and will practice with one dimensional loops for the rest of the day!

Comment: For some bizarre reason I got it into my head that I was limited to three parameters - also, I didn't use the += operator. You've helped me a great deal and I thank you very much!

Comment: And thanks for the help in getting my head around how to use this site. Your answer was awesome! :)